# What does it mean that my resource manager does not have an open port 8032?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I have my YARN resource manager on a different node than my namenode, and I can see that *something* is running, which I take to be the resource manager. Ports 8031 and 8030 are bound, but not port 8032, to which my client tries to connect.

I am on CDH 5.3.1, and the following is part of the output of `lsof -i`

```
java      12478         yarn  230u  IPv4  61325      0t0  TCP hadoop2.adastragrp.com:48797->hadoop2.adastragrp.com:8031 (ESTABLISHED)
java      13753         yarn  159u  IPv4  61302      0t0  TCP hadoop2.adastragrp.com:8031 (LISTEN)
java      13753         yarn  170u  IPv4  61308      0t0  TCP hadoop2.adastragrp.com:8030 (LISTEN)
java      13753         yarn  191u  IPv4  61326      0t0  TCP hadoop2.adastragrp.com:8031->hadoop2.adastragrp.com:48797 (ESTABLISHED)
```

How do I diagnose what's wrong here? I suspect that the resource manager is running, but can't bind to port 8032, but I have no idea why that could be.

In the cloudera manager, the ResourceManager is shown as having good health, but at the same time I get this report:

> ResourceManager summary: hadoop2.adastragrp.com (Availability:
>   Unknown, Health: Good). This health test is bad because the Service
>   Monitor did not find an active ResourceManager.

[Edit]

I can execute `yarn application -list` locally on the resource manager node, but when I do the same on a different node, it tries to connect to the resource manager correctly, but fails to do so. Both nodes are connected, can ping each other, and so on. I disabled the iptables service on the VM.

nmap output:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE REASON
8032/tcp filtered unknown host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha, on CentOS 6 stopping the iptables service didn't really disable the firewall. I had to disable it with system-config-firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Wether the port was occupied by other process? For example, you stop your hadoop cluster abnormally, result in some process still running. If so, try to `ps -e|grep java`,and kill it.